# jQuery.getJSON causes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" for youtube oembed

Tags: jquery, json, youtube, jsonp, oembed

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DB-m6JDYRFvk&callback=?', 
           function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

When curling that URL I get this response:

```
{
    "provider_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
    "title": "Coder Girl",
    "html": "\u003cobject width=\"425\" height=\"344\"\u003e\u003cparam name=\"movie\" value=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/B-m6JDYRFvk?version=3\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cparam name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cparam name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cembed src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/B-m6JDYRFvk?version=3\" type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/embed\u003e\u003c\/object\u003e",
    "author_name": "dalechase",
    "height": 344,
    "thumbnail_width": 480,
    "width": 425,
    "version": "1.0",
    "author_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/dalechase",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/i3.ytimg.com\/vi\/B-m6JDYRFvk\/hqdefault.jpg",
    "type": "video",
    "thumbnail_height": 360
}
```

But when I try to execute the above code, I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` (Chrome). It looks like the problem might have something to do with the escaping of the forward slashes, or maybe that jQuery is sending a `JSONP` request, but the response is pure `JSON`.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube (as of the time of this answer) oembed doesn't support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) with their requests, so what you're getting back is correct...but it's not what you *need*.  What you *need* for JSONP calls would look like this:

```
functionName({
    "provider_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
    "title": "Coder Girl",
    "html": "\u003cobject width=\"425\" height=\"344\"\u003e\u003cparam name=\"movie\" value=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/B-m6JDYRFvk?version=3\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cparam name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cparam name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"\u003e\u003c\/param\u003e\u003cembed src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/B-m6JDYRFvk?version=3\" type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"425\" height=\"344\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/embed\u003e\u003c\/object\u003e",
    "author_name": "dalechase",
    "height": 344,
    "thumbnail_width": 480,
    "width": 425,
    "version": "1.0",
    "author_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/dalechase",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/i3.ytimg.com\/vi\/B-m6JDYRFvk\/hqdefault.jpg",
    "type": "video",
    "thumbnail_height": 360
});
```

...since what comes back currently  is **not valid JavaScript** (by itself, and that's what it is), and that's how JSONP works, the response actually needs to be executable JavaScript.

You can get the same error by just plopping that code straight in your page in a `<script>` block ([see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RruQ4/)).

---

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're trying to do, but if you're just after the embedding piece, I recommend a plugin like [jQuery-oembed](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-oembed/) to do that.  If you're after the data...you'll need something on your server to process the JSON, then get the data from your server after that.

Comment: Ah it looks like this is correct. It also looks like jQuery-oembed uses oohEmbed as an endpoint for providers who don't support JSONP. I think I'll end up processing the request on the server, like you said, or using embed.ly as a single endpoint, since it supports JSONP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use JSONP anymore with jQuery as of version 1.5. Try $.ajax() and set crossDomain:true and remove all your ?callback wrappers and see if it works. It's a much more reliable method and the syntax is much cleaner.

Comment: Just tried it, and it looks like it doesn't work. You still need to set `dataType : 'jsonp'` to get the request through, and the unexpected token error is still thrown. Also, according to the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), crossDomain defaults to true for cross-domain requests anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better alternative would be to replace your cross domain call with a call to a web service running on your own server that runs the call for you.  My guess is Chrome is blocking the cross domain request.

Answer (score 0):

Stringify the result works for me.

```
$.getJSON('your_url_here', function(data) {
    console.log(data);  //"Object { Json content }"
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);  //"{ Json content }", the "Object" literal is removed.
    var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonString); //Parse should work now.
});
```